# AD7190 noise performance calculation

Tags: adc, voltage-reference

I'm using ad7190 to sample single-ended voltage. The rms input-refered noise is given by the datasheet. However, the datasheet only specified the noise with 5V reference, whereas I'm using 4.096V reference.

How should I calculate the noise now? Should I scale the noise down proportionally?

The noise in the datasheet is also test with differential input, does it makes a difference if my input is single-ended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of the noise specifications are listed as typical, it is not that critical as to how you model your system. In any case, I doubt that using a 4 volt reference instead of a 5 volt reference would make any difference as far as input noise is concerned since the reference only affects the digital part of the circuit. Grounding one side of the input will probably reduce the effective noise by a factor of √2 which, again, is not that all significant.

Answer (score 0):

The PGA, the external reference and the ADC each contribute their own portion of the noise. If the datasheet does not state the respective contribution it is hard or impossible to make a precise statement about what happens when you change one component.

However, generally voltage references are quite noisy compared to both opamps and ADCs. And lower references have proportionally less noise voltage. In this case, using a lower reference of the same type as the 5V one, can make your reading less noisy. You get the same amount of noisy bits, but since the bits are smaller, the rms voltage noise will be smaller.

But there are also many scenarios where this would be not the case and where you gain nothing. 1) If the new reference is noisier than the 5v reference..2) if your input signal is noisier than the total noise of the AD7190 3) if other components inside the AD7190 were dominating noise.